# How can I delete a entry in swift permanently using FileManager

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new at programming with swift. I programmed a app where you can add some elements to a tableview. I saved the data via FileManager on my simulator iPhone. Now I want to delete a element from my table view permanently.

I used a method called commit editingStyle to delete a row in my table view. This is working, but if I restart my app the element is still there.

```
//create the file 
let dataFilePath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("Item.plist")
//delete the file 
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
                itemArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Share more code on how items are added/saved to the file? You might have to save the file again by removing the item from the dataSource(i.e, `itemArray`).

Comment: Oh yes. I called the function to safe my items after tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic) and it worked. Thanks m8

Answer (score 0):

this is to add a new item

```
@IBAction func addNewToDoItem(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
var textField = UITextField()

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Neues Todo", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

let action = UIAlertAction(title: "ToDo hinzufügen", style: .default) { (action) in

    // Item was der Nutzer ertsellen wird
    let itemObject = Item(title: textField.text!)       // hinzufügen, das was der Nutzer ins Textfield eingibt
    self.itemArray.append(itemObject)

    // Daten dauerhaft speichern
    self.saveItems()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .default) { (cancelAction) in
    // Abbrechen
}

alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
    alertTextField.placeholder = "Todo eintragen"
    textField = alertTextField
}
alert.addAction(action)
alert.addAction(cancelAction)
present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

safe data:

```
func saveItems() {

let encoder = PropertyListEncoder()

do {
    let data = try encoder.encode(itemArray)
    try data.write(to: dataFilePath!)
} catch {
    print("Fehler beim schreiben der Dateien", error)
}
```

}

and this is my itemArray with his own class:

```
var itemArray = [Item]()

class Item: Codable {       // Aus Encodable und Decodable wird Codable

var title : String = ""
var done : Bool = false

init(title : String) {
    self.title = title
}

init(title: String, done: Bool) {
    self.title = title
    self.done = done
}
```

}